# Assign a Viewbag from an @HTML.Action request

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, actionmethod

I am firing a DevExpress Gridivew when a page is requested

```
@Html.Action("ActionName")
```

Inside this Actionesult method, the code populates the gridview and I would like to use a viewbag to show the total number of items inside the grid.

```
// we have the row count - so assign it. 
ViewBag.NoOpenItems = List<People>.Count;

return PartialView("GridView", List<People>);
```

So once the grid is populated and the viewbag assigned, the viewbag doesn't show anything inside it.

```
<h5>Total @ViewBag.NoOpenItems</h5>
```

However, when I assign a value to the viewbag inside the main GET Action method on page load, the viewbag value is shown correctly on the page, so I am guessing its to do with assigning the viewbag inside the action method? - Actually as I write this, I am guessing the problem lies with the action method returning a `PartialView`?

if so, does anyone know how I can achieve what I like to do?

Comment: `List<object>.Count` isn't valid C# syntax.

Comment: I know.... the code above illustrates how I am setting the viewbag so using `.count` from a `IList` but it isnt the syntax that matters.

Comment: create a ViewModel and set its propery and passs that model to view

Comment: i agree with that, that is what I normally do but for such a small addition I like to use a `viewbag`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use it in View if **Model** is `List<T>` instead of putting in **ViewBag**:

```
@model List<People>

@if(Model != null)
{
<h5>Total @Model.Count</h5>
}
```

or:

```
<h5> @(Model != null ? Model.Count : 0)</h5>
```

Comment: I like the idea and thats how I would do it however, assigning the count before returning the `PartialView` doesn't fire that code again so the `@Model` will always be NULL

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gridivew Pager property to show no of record

```
settings.SettingsPager.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
    settings.SettingsPager.FirstPageButton.Visible = true;
    settings.SettingsPager.LastPageButton.Visible = true;
    settings.SettingsPager.PageSizeItemSettings.Visible = true;
    settings.SettingsPager.PageSizeItemSettings.Items = new string[] { "10", "20", "50" };
```

for more you can visit [Devexpress GridView page](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/DataBindingToLargeDatabase)